# PrimeFaces DataTable editing with autocomplete in pojo

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with a datatable which have to display various informations about Mailbox objects. One of these informations is the owner of the Mailbox which is stored by its id in Mailbox object. In output I solved this with a method in backing bean that retrieve the username by the mailbox object. In input I thought to use autocomplete with pojo but I can't exactly realize how do this.

My jsf page:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{bean.mailboxes}" var="m" editable="true">
  <!-- other table -->
  <p:column headerText="Owner">
    <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">  
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.userByMailbox(m)}" />  
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
        <!-- here comes autocomplete -->
      </f:facet>  
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And my bean:

```
public class Bean {

// Other properties and methods

List<Mailbox> mailboxes;

public List<Mailbox> getMailboxes() {
    if (mailboxes == null) {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Mailbox.findAll");
        mailboxes = q.getResultList();
    }

    return mailboxes;
}

public User getUserByMailbox(Mailbox m) {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUsrId");
    q.setParameter("usrId", m.getUsrId());
    return (User)q.getSingleResult();
}
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You're not entirely new here, so you should know you're supposed to show code

Comment: I think this example from [Primefaces autocompletes](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf;jsessionid=h6hn1ic6vp4i1a3z0s1vp2fpr) is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is wrong.

In `Mailbox`, replace

```
@Column
private Long usrId;
```

by

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="usrId")
private User user;
```

This way you can just use`#{m.user}` instead of `#{bean.userByMailbox(m)}`. This way the property is also writable (perhaps you actually got a `PropertyNotWritableException` while attempting to use this EL expression in `<p:autoComplete value>`; in the future questions tell that so instead of asking an overly generic question).

Note that this concrete problem has essentially nothing to do with JSF nor `<p:autoComplete>`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new to java, so I don't even know about these JPA annotation, I thought there wasn't a way to do that. Thank you BalusC anyway.